# how to make Multiple-calc operation in one click button -android-

Tags: android, android-edittext

i try to make Multiple-calc operation in one click but when i click on button done its show error so how can i modification this code to be able to calc all of this operations in one click with out any errors . here is the code

```
public class calcit extends Activity {

EditText onehighx,twowightx,threefinallresultx,four100x,fiveresultof100x,sixresultofresultx;
Button donee;
BigDecimal onehigh,twowight,threefinallresult,four100,fiveresultof100,sixresultofresult;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calcit);

    donee = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    onehighx = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.high);// high
    twowightx = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Weight);//Weight
    threefinallresultx = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finall_result);//result =Weight * result of result 100
    four100x = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e100);//100
    fiveresultof100x = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.re_of_100);// result of 100 = high * 100 
    sixresultofresultx = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result_of_100_100);// result of result 100 /ex : 1.75*1.75

    donee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            onehigh = new BigDecimal(onehighx.getText().toString());
            twowight= new BigDecimal(twowightx.getText().toString());
            threefinallresult = new BigDecimal(threefinallresultx.getText().toString());
            four100 = new BigDecimal(four100x.getText().toString());
            fiveresultof100 = new BigDecimal(fiveresultof100x.getText().toString());
            sixresultofresult = new BigDecimal(sixresultofresultx.getText().toString());

           //---here i want to fix this code to be able to show all of this Multiple-calc operations in 
            //(threefinallresultx)------

            fiveresultof100x.setText((onehigh).divide(four100).toString());
            sixresultofresultx.setText((fiveresultof100).multiply(fiveresultof100).toString());
            threefinallresultx.setText((twowight).divide(sixresultofresult).toString());

        }
    });



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong you want to do calculations on values fetched from Edittexts but you are instead trying to divide or multiply setText boxes and not the values contained in them. So just fetch values in appropriate format and calculate them normally such as

```
onehigh=onehigh/four100;
fiveresultof100=fiveresultof100*fiveresultof100;
twowight=twowight/sixresultofresult;
```

and then set them in textboxes

```
fiveresultof100x.setText(onehigh);
ixresultofresultx.setText(fiveresultof100);
threefinallresultx.setText(twowight);
```